# Authentication with Blogger API for Windows desktop app

Tags: .net, authentication, oauth, blogger, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm trying to develop a C# Windows application to perform some custom Google Blogger tasks. Using the Google.Apis.Blogger.v3 Nuget package, I've successfully queried my public test blogs' posts, but now I want to make it capable of querying a private blogs' posts and performing administrative tasks on the blog.

I've been through [this page](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) and a bunch of related pages on OAuth. They all seem really vague. That page is the closest I've come to seeing how to actually use OAuth with the API. I don't understand why it uses the hardcoded string "user", though. Where does "user" come from?

Additionally, I don't see how this would give me access to a blog. I guess it will authenticate my application, but my application doesn't have the rights to administer any blog it wants. Does my app's user have to go get their own OAuth ID & secret and provide it to my app? Not user friendly. I imagine my application just allowing the user to enter the URL to their blog, their user name, and their password, and then going and authenticating as that user via the API and sending that token with each request. Is there a way for me to access a blog using just a user name & password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by looking at some of the other better documented APIs. The [youtube API docs had a page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/installed-apps) that explained it in more detail. Basically, Google doesn't want users entering their credentials into your app. Instead you send them to a google page that allows them to authorize your application. You pass your OAuth info to that page so that it can identify your app and ask the user if they want to allow access. This is where it gets a little hairy for a desktop app. That page can post back to a localhost URL, but since most users won't have a web server, it also has the option of putting the response in the response web page's title. Look for the Google oauth `redirect_uri` parameter for info on this.

The Google .NET API has built in support for this (See [GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync and UserCredential](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)). It can read the client_secret.json file generated by the developer console for you, open the client browser and send the oauth request for access, read the response, and close the browser when it's done. [This link with a Console App example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) really helped me with that.

The only part I'm still unclear on is the hardcoded "user" parameter sent to `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()`, but it seems to work.